# Inconsistent synonym behavior after other filters in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

When performing a synonym substitution filter after other filters in Elasticsearch, I am finding that certain substitutions are not performed. As a minimum example, consider the following index:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "english_stop": {
                    "type": "stop",
                    "stopwords": "_english_"
                },
                "porter2_stemmer": {
                    "type": "stemmer",
                    "language": "porter"
                },
                "stemmed_synonyms": {
                    "type": "synonym",
                    "synonyms": [
                        "domest violenc => domest_violenc",
                        "male femal => male_female",
                        "formerli incarcer => formerly_incarcerated"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "with_sub": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "english_stop",
                        "porter2_stemmer",
                        "stemmed_synonyms"
                    ]
                },
                "no_sub": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "english_stop",
                        "porter2_stemmer"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I run the following `_analyze` query:

```
{
    "analyzer": "with_sub",
    "text": "Domestic violence. Domestics and violences. Male, females. Male? (and female)."
}
```

As expected, I get back `domest_violenc`, `domest_violenc`, `male_femal`, `male_femal`.

I then run *this* `_analyze` query:

```
{
    "analyzer": "with_sub",
    "text": "Formerly incarcerated."
}
```

I get back the stemmed versions as written in `synonyms`, but not the synonym substitution itself:

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "formerli",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "incarcer",
            "start_offset": 9,
            "end_offset": 21,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

If I run the same query with the `no_sub` analyzer, I get the same result. I can't see how this case differs from the preceding cases. What am I missing?

Comment: Adding to my mystification: I found that if I used the **unstemmed** versions of the terms in the synonym filter, it works. In that case, it still ignores case, plurality, and stop words. This suggests that all three of the preceding filters are acting on the synonym filter in some way, but not in the expected way.